# Inductor in DC circuits and DC/DC converters

Tags: dc, dc-dc-converter, inductor

Quick question which is somewhat confusing me.

So I understand that an inductor will have no effect in a DC circuit and merely acts as a resistor, as no change in current will be seen.

However for DC/DC converters does the principle of operation not involve an inductor, whereby the voltage can be stepped up across the inductor?

I am wondering how this can be the case if inductors do not effect DC  circuits?

Thanks

Comment: You're right to ask. However, DC/DC convertors are actually DC/AC/DC convertors. The inductors are in the AC bit...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inductor-based DC to DC converters use one or more switches to create changing conditions at the inductor.

In its simplest form, a step-up, or boost, converter repeatedly stores energy in an inductor by connecting it to a source, then releases the energy into the load.